# Django contact form sending email back to my own email address

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username    =   request.POST['username']
        phone       =   request.POST['phone']
        customer_email  =   request.POST['customer_email']
        subject     =   request.POST['subject']
        message     =   request.POST['message']

        #send Email
        send_mail(subject, message, customer_email, ['myemail@gmail.com'])

        return render(request, 'contact.html', {'username': username })

    else:
        return render(request, 'contact.html', {})
```

This is my html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'contact' %}" id="contact-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Name" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
      <input type="email" name="customer_email" placeholder="Email" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
      <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group">
      <button class="theme-btn btn-style-one" type="submit" name="submit-form">Submit Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the form I have that should send an email to customer_email, but instead I am getting the email back to me. That is, sender and recipient are both same. What is the issue here? Also is it possible to add the customer's email and phone number in the email message?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email#django.core.mail.send_mail) for `send_mail` says:

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, ...)
```

so when you call

```
send_mail(subject, message, customer_email, ['myemail@gmail.com'])
```

you're plugging in `customer_email` to `from_email` and your email address to `recipient_list`... so yeah, you get the email since you tell the computer to do just that.

Maybe:

```
username = request.POST['username']
phone = request.POST['phone']
customer_email = request.POST['customer_email']
subject = request.POST['subject']
message = request.POST['message']

content = f"""
{message}

Username: {username}
Phone: {phone}
Email: {customer_email}
"""

send_mail(
  subject=subject,
  message=content,
  from_email=None,  # use default sender from settings
  recipient_list=[customer_email],
)
```

Just be careful about spam – an open contact form like this will easily get your address or server blocked around the world since you're essentially allowing anyone to use it to send a message to anyone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I will take your input and include a captcha for this.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want the email to be stored in the database, you must also design the email model.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34167933)